# can't remotely connect to mysql database in cpanel with python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, cpanel

I tried to connect remotely to my database in cpanel in all ways but it won't let me, does anyone know why it doesn't give me access?

```
HOST = "xxxxxxxxx"
DATABASE = "xxxxxxxxx"
USER = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
PASSWORD = "xxxxxxx"

db_connection = mysql.connect(host=HOST, database=DATABASE, user=USER, password=PASSWORD)
print("Connected to:", db_connection.get_server_info())


#####################################################################################

python3 sqlConect.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miguel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 509, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miguel/Desktop/python/sqlConect.py", line 61, in <module>
    db_connection = mysql.connect(host=HOST, database=DATABASE, user=USER, password=PASSWORD)
  File "/home/miguel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/miguel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/miguel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/home/miguel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/home/miguel/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 511, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'industriasbjt.com:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

Comment: Where is your connection originating from? Have you whitelisted that IP address on your server(in cpanel)? Does your mysql user have appropriate privileges? Is your mysql server listening only to the local host?

Comment: I already whitelist my ip, my mysql server in cpanel listens to the local server, I really don't know if my user has the appropriate privileges

Comment: If it's bound to only the localhost then that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In cpanel when you try to connect remotely and access is denied by port 3306, you have to contact the cpanel provider and check the plans that give remote access, because if port 3306 is blocked the remote connection plan may is limited, it's just a matter of talking to the provider that provides the cpanel